# Mr. Robot S2 Episode 7, is Ray an illusion?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

In Mr. Robot S2 Episode 7, at the end, Elliot tells don't be too mad and he is in prison. He acknowledges basketball game, church, his friend all are inside the prison.

Does it mean Ray and his site are also illusions? If so, what about him informing the FBI about Ray's dark site? Then, for what reason is he in prison?

Comment: I've fixed up *some* of your grammar, but I'll have to leave the rest to someone who's watched the show and knows precisely what you're talking about. I don't want to accidentally change the question to the point where it conflicts with your intent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Ray and his site are not an illusion. Ray is the jail warden where Elliot has been imprisoned.
Elliot is in prison for stealing Lenny's dog. Lenny is Krista's ex-boyfriend.
The police comes to arrest Elliot in [Season 2 Episode 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mr._Robot_episodes#Season_2_(2016)).

> The knock on Elliot's door was the police to arrest him for hacking
>   Lenny, Krista's ex, and stealing his dog. He pleads guilty; he's in
>   jail the next day with Ray as warden, establishing his illusion. Even
>   though his sentence is for 18 months, he's released 86 days later due
>   to cost control measures.